# iTerm2 Coprocess Debugging

Tags: python-2.7, iterm2

I'm attempting to develop a coprocess plugin in python for iTerm2 but am running into some issues.  I have a script that takes input from STDIN and sends it across the network to a listening daemon.  This works fine when run from the command line, however when I activate the coprocess either via the menu or a trigger I just see a brief flash of the coprocess icon in the upper right corner.  Googling does not reveal whether or not iTerm2 sends output anywhere that I can examine.  I have looked at all of the system logs in Console.app but there is nothing there.  I've also tried Toggling the Debug Logging in iTerm but I do not see any coprocess data in there.  Anyone know if/where to find the STDOUT/STDERR of a coprocess script?

Answer (score 0):

Stdin and stdout are hooked up to the tty as described in [copresses documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-coprocesses.html)  (and may be silent or visible depending on how it is set up). As for stderr, (judging by the lack of any redirect of fd 2 in [Coprocess.m source](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/f61411bb4f13145bce0269f005711ee45c574e35/sources/Coprocess.m#L66)) it is the same as stderr of iTerm2 itself. In order to see the error of copresseses, you can launch iTerm2 from Terminal in the foreground (`open /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2`), interact with iTerm2, and view the stderr within Terminal.